# Centraliser of Automorphism Group of a Group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group with $Z(G) = 1$ therefore the centralizer subgroup is trivial.

Let consider $Aut(G)$: If we know that $C_{Aut(G)}(Inn(G)) = 1$  holds too for $Inn(G) =\{\alpha_g \in Aut(G) | \alpha_g(h) = h^g\} \subset Aut(G)$, is it true that then $Z(Aut(G)) = 1$ holds too?

If yes, how to see it? 
If no, do we need stronger conditions for $G$ or $Inn(G)$ making it holding?

Comment: Yes, this is true for any group with $Z(G)=1$, without any extra assumption. $Z({\rm Aut}(G))$ must have trivial intersection with ${\rm Inn}(G) \cong G$, but then it would centralize ${\rm Inn}(G)$, and so would coorrespond to trivial automorphisms of $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and this is obvious: in any group, all centralizers contain the  center of the group.

Comment: But for the weaker condition $Z(Inn(G))=1$ instead of $C_{Aut(G)}(Inn(G)) = 1$ it does not more hold?